# How to translate a 2D histogram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to translate the histogram along a vector, say `(2, 2)`.

```
axes.imshow(np.transpose(WeightOrDigitalMap),
            vmin=constants.FIDELITY_THRESHOLD, vmax=constants.FIDELITY_UPPER_LIMIT,
            cmap=cm.gray, origin='bottom')
```

I have tried `extent` but no luck.

```
axes.imshow(np.transpose(WeightOrDigitalMap),
            extent = [min(x)+2, max(x)+2, min(y)+2, max(y)+2]
            vmin=constants.FIDELITY_THRESHOLD, vmax=constants.FIDELITY_UPPER_LIMIT,
            cmap=cm.gray, origin='bottom')
```

How may I do it?

Comment: What did you try with `extent`?  That is my first thought as to what to do.

Comment: @tcaswell please kindly refer to the updated part.

Comment: And what does that do?  That looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `min(x)` is what you want?

If you start from:

```
axes.imshow(np.transpose(WeightOrDigitalMap),
        vmin=constants.FIDELITY_THRESHOLD, vmax=constants.FIDELITY_UPPER_LIMIT,
        cmap=cm.gray, origin='bottom')
```

you would translate the image by `(2,2)` by using

```
axes.imshow(WeightOrDigitalMap.T,
        vmin=constants.FIDELITY_THRESHOLD, vmax=constants.FIDELITY_UPPER_LIMIT,
        cmap=cm.gray, origin='bottom',
        extent=(2, WeightOrDigitalMap.shape[0]+2, 2, WeightOrDigitalMap.shape[1]+2)
```

Without specifying an extent, matplotlib will use

```
extent=(0, WeightOrDigitalMap.shape[0], 0, WeightOrDigitalMap.shape[1]
```